# How do I make an emission object invisible when the emission is off?

Tags: emission

I'm trying to animate flashing text around an object but I do not want to see the text when the emission is off.

It's just an emission node to material output with key frames on emission strength.

How would I make the text invisible while keeping it's animated emission?

[image: Visible black text I'd like to be invisible.]

Comment: It depends on the render engine, what node you are using, and how easily you can transfer the existing keyframes. If the keyframes can be transferred easily, I would try using a mix shader node with transparency as the other shader, and animating it’s factor instead. Otherwise, you may be able to emit light from a fully transparent Principled BSDF material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EEVEE solution:

Node setup:

By changing the threshold and the value you can determine the pulsing speed/duration.

[image]

[image]

Important:

Change the blend mode to this:

[image]

[image]

CYCLES:

For cycles it works the same, just add this compositing setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, this was an excellent breakdown.

Comment: You are welcome